# Event quotation plugin for Magento OR Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, magento, events, quotes

Im  starting to develop a new website for a client, it is an events hire site for a sound and lighting company.

What they want is a system where they have all their products listed with their hire prices and an add to quote button. 
They would like the users to be able to select different options with each products e.g. a configurable product in `Magento`.
After the user has selected all the products they want in their event quote, they want there to be a button which says "go to my quote" or something along those lines.
At this page the user can review their quote, add the dates and times of the event and add any additional notes.

This all then gets sent to the backend of whatever system we use and can be dealt with from there.

My question: What platform would be better for this, `Wordpress` OR `Magento`?
And do you know of any plugins that support all the options i displayed above, for either platform (preferable free)??

Thanks very much

Comment: Did you look into this extension for your requirements https://magecomp.com/magento-email-cart.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess this question is outdated, but in case someone has the same question: Magento in combination with Cart2Quote should do the trick.

**Wordpress**: One way is to use Wordpress, WooCommerce in combination with something like 'WooCommerce Request a Quote'.
The downside is, most WooCommerce quote modules are more advanced form modules and just provide in some basic functionality. (Which is perfect if that is exactly what you need)

**Magento**: One other way is to use Magento and Cart2Quote.
The downside is, its way more expensive.

I personally would use Magento, because in my opinion it is by far a more powerful store solution.
However you find yourself more often in a situation that you need a (external) developer and those are expensive. (The upside is that Magento developers are in most cases great developers, you get what you pay for.)

If your goal is to keep the cost as low as possible, than I would go for the Wordpress solution.